# Нажатие на изображение,чтобы потом появилась информация по центру об этом изображении

Tags: javascript, jquery

Как сделать так,чтобы при нажатии на картинку,высвечивалась информация по середине страницы.При клике на любое фото должно появляться на странице блок с описанием этой картинки

Comment: Используйте слайдер

Comment: Используй дата атрибуты и вытаскивай при  клике в нужную область.

Comment: Можете написать как это делать?

Comment: Не забывайте выбирать правильный ответ если вам помогли.

Answer (score 3):

В зависимости от размера контента и его содержимого, можно пойти разными путями.
Как вам уже указали в комментариях, используйте `data`-атрибуты, в которых укажите нужный текст.  Подойдет для небольшого текста, не забывайте экранировать кавычки при необходимости.

```js
$("#images img").click(function(){
  $("#title").text( $(this).data('title'));
});
```

```css
#images img { cursor: pointer; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="images">
  <img data-title="Chrome"  src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/647f715e-96d2-11e6-960f-00163ec9f5fa/965337810/chrome-Google_Chrome_logo.png"/>      
  <img data-title="FireFox" src="https://images.sftcdn.net/images/t_app-logo-l,f_auto,dpr_auto/p/f484e040-96d2-11e6-9a72-00163ed833e7/1808152659/mozilla-firefox-firefox-logo-2017.png" />      
  <img data-title="Edge"    src="https://dl1.cbsistatic.com/i/r/2017/10/05/463160a4-2ecf-493c-ac30-3b44e93bf58e/thumbnail/64x64/1a0e3f241e390328b5ebd832ac845feb/imgingest-7226227203991583976.png" />      
  <img data-title="Yandex"  src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-FQSzR0aKQP8/VYV38PBT_9I/AAAAAAAAA4M/aidnc-p6T9Q/s1600/64px-Yandex_browser_logo.png" />
  <img data-title="Tor"     src="https://addons-media.operacdn.com/media/extensions/45/228745/0.1.0-rev1/icons/icon_64x64_dd44e2521dce2abc041a6ee280516f32.png" />
</div>

<h1 id="title"></h1>
```

Можно также сделать отдельно картинки, отдельно блоки с текстом. Изначально блоки скрыты. Картинка и блок должны иметь связанный идентификатор. При клике в картинку показывать соответствующий блок.

Comment: <script> 
 
 
 $(document).ready(function(){

  $('.img-2').css('position','absolute').css('bottom','20px').css('left','10px').click(function(){
    $("ello").text($('body').data('hello'));
  }) 
  
 
 
 
  

 




 });
 
 </script>


 <img src='images/2.png' alt='' class='img-2' width='150'>

Comment: Этот код нужен для того чтобы картинка была в слево низу и при нажатии на неё высвечивалась информация по середине экрана?